# I am getting an error ./test1hc.sh[59]: [[[: not found in if condition while executing the below shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

```
exec > /apps/jobs/logs/healthcheck.log 2>&1

set -x

#!/bin/ksh

. ~/vdom.profile

db2 CONNECT to $DATABASE_MIF user $DBUSER_MIF using $DBPASS_MIF 

rm -r /apps/jobs/scripts/alerts/health_check/tempdata/*
cd /apps/jobs/scripts/alerts/health_check/tempdata/

emailalertgroup1='kantheti_srividya@xxx.com,naveen_kishore@xxx.com' 

param=`db2 -x "select dflt_value from param_def where param_group_id = 'COUNTFL'"`

param1=`db2 -x "select dflt_value from param_def where param_group_id = 'COUNTM'"`
    
amempty=`db2 -x "select con.router_id ,count(tran.MESSAGE_ID) as failure_count ,  con.router_description  from MIF_ROUTER_CONFIG con
LEFT JOIN tran_log tran ON con.ROUTER_ID = tran.ROUTER_ID where con.EXECUTION_FREQUENCY = '1' and tran.RESULT_CODE in (select dflt_value from param_def where param_group_id = 'STATUSCD') and tran.created_dttm > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-$param1 MINUTE group by con.router_id,con.router_description HAVING count(tran.MESSAGE_ID)>=$param"`

db2 "select con.router_id ,count(tran.MESSAGE_ID) as failure_count ,  con.router_description  from MIF_ROUTER_CONFIG con
LEFT JOIN tran_log tran ON con.ROUTER_ID = tran.ROUTER_ID where con.EXECUTION_FREQUENCY = '1' and tran.RESULT_CODE in (select dflt_value from param_def where param_group_id = 'STATUSCD') and tran.created_dttm > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-$param1 MINUTE group by con.router_id,con.router_description HAVING count(tran.MESSAGE_ID)>=$param" > /apps/jobs/scripts/alerts/health_check/tempdata/failure_count.txt

CurrentDay=$(date '+%A')
CurrentTime=$(date +"%H:%M")
    
cd /apps/jobs/scripts/alerts/health_check/tempdata/
 
    
if [[[ $amempty != "" ] -a [ $CurrentDay == "Friday" -a $CurrentTime -ge "10:00" ] ] -o [ [ $amempty != "" ] -a [ $CurrentDay == "Sunday" -a $CurrentTime -le "08:00" ]]]
    
then

echo "Hi Team, 

Please treat this with HIGH Priority. Below are the list of router with the failure count. Please login to MIF and take necessary action. Job did not fail."

cat failure_count.txt

else
    
    echo The message flow is normal..!! No action Required..!!

   fi
   
exit
```

Comment: `[[[`...`]]]` construct I've never seen, so I merely want to point out the https://www.shellcheck.net/ which could be useful.

Comment: The square brackets do not nest. There is a [ ] syntax and a separate [[ ]] syntax that can contain multiple tests with appropriate binary operators, but none of it works like C round brackets.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such operator as `[[[`. Paste your code into https://shellcheck.net/ or deploy `shellcheck` on a machine locally to see other errors and recommendations.

Three other possibly related issues for you to consider,

- There should be no code above the `#!/bin/ksh` line. Such `#!` lines should always be the *first* line of any script to identify the shell with which the script should be run
- Make sure the script is executable and you call it as if it's a program. (For example, do not use `ksh script.sh` but instead use `./script.sh`. This is so that the `#!` line is considered.)
- For consistency don't mix backtick evaluation (eg `` param=`db2 ...` `` ) with nested evaluation (`CurrentDay=$(date '+%A')`). Move to using just the more modern `$( ...)` style throughout